# Get most active users sort by comment count

Tags: comments, users

how can I display a list of the most active users (with permalink and thumb) sort by comments count?

I found this on WP Codex that list all the users, but I don't know how to sort by comment count.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'number' => 10,
    'orderby' => name
);

// The Query
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

// User Loop
if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
    foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
        echo '<p>' . $user->display_name . '</p>';
    }
} else {
    echo 'No users found.';
}
?>
```

Thank you very much in advance

EDIT

I found this code on the web:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$where = 'WHERE comment_approved = 1 AND user_id <> 0';
$comment_counts = (array) $wpdb->get_results("
        SELECT user_id, COUNT( * ) AS total
        FROM {$wpdb->comments}
        {$where}
        GROUP BY user_id
    ", object);

    echo '<ul>';

    foreach ( $comment_counts as $count ) {
      $user = get_userdata($count->user_id);
    //echo "<pre>"; print_r($count); echo "</pre>";
    //echo "<pre>"; print_r($user); echo "</pre>";
      echo '<li>User ' . get_avatar( $user->ID ) . "<a href='" . get_author_posts_url($user->ID) . "'>" . $user->display_name . "</a>" . ' comment count is ' . $count->total . "</li>" . '
    ';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    ?>
```

I added the author link and the thumb and it seems it works. Do you think it is correct `get_avatar( $user->ID )` and `get_author_posts_url($user->ID)`?

But the problem is always the same.. How can I sort the authors list by comment count?

EDIT

I solve the issue.

the right code is:

```
<?php
        global $wpdb;
        $where = 'WHERE comment_approved = 1 AND user_id <> 0';
        $comment_counts = (array) $wpdb->get_results("
        SELECT user_id, COUNT( * ) AS total
        FROM {$wpdb->comments}
        {$where}
        GROUP BY user_id
        ORDER BY total DESC
    ", object);

            echo '<ul>';

            foreach ( $comment_counts as $count ) {
              $user = get_userdata($count->user_id);
            //echo "<pre>"; print_r($count); echo "</pre>";
            //echo "<pre>"; print_r($user); echo "</pre>";
              echo "<li>";
              echo get_avatar( $user->ID ) . "<a href='" . get_author_posts_url($user->ID) . "'>" . $user->display_name . "</a>";
              echo "<p> Numero di commenti: " . $count->total . "</p>" ;
              echo "</li>"

            ;
            }
            echo '</ul>';


    ?>
```

with the help of a WP Support Member I filter the comment counts by this:

```
ORDER BY total DESC
```

Thank you

Comment: Link to the source of the code please as it's not your work. You found it on the web, you mean someones website?

Comment: Sorry @BradDalton. I found on the Wordpress Support: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/registered-users-comment-count?replies=10

Comment: Try WP_Query`'orderby' => 'comment_count'`. Not tested but an idea.

Comment: unfortunately doesn't work :(