# display most active user sort by comment count [Solved]

Tags: php

i'm using "WP_User_Query" to displaying the most active user orderby = "post_count" in front and It works fine,

now i want to display the most active user based on comment count in front

i will be appreciate it if anyone could help me on this.

Comment: This is not possible via `WP_User_Query` on its own as it doesn't count comments in this query, therefore there is no easy `orderby` parameter to use.
You may be able to work something out using something [like this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/104782/count-number-of-user-comments-with-a-specific-comment-meta-value) - ideally you would get the array of comments only once to build an order of most popular commenters (maybe using `array_count_values`)

Comment: @Bysander i understand what you mean but i don't think that i can make this work.  could you please be more specific ? like a snippet or somthing else that could help me ...

Comment: for anyone who may need this feature too : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/195155/get-most-active-users-sort-by-comment-count https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/308517/how-to-display-only-first-value-of-database-column-in-wordpress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this

```
$user = new wp_user(get_current_user_id());
```

function commentCount() {

```
global $user;
global $wpdb;
$count = $wpdb->get_var('SELECT COUNT(comment_ID) FROM ' . $wpdb->comments. ' WHERE comment_author_email = "' . $user->data->user_email . '" and comment_approved = 1');
return $count;
```

}

echo '';

echo commentCount();

Comment: thanks , i already did it and it worked , but there is only one problem that still exist
how can i get the count based on date ? 
For example most commenter in current month

Answer (score 0):

here is some code I have typed up straight from the codex - I have not tested or run it as I am at work but should put you on the right track. I have included all the pages to learn more about each function / step in the process. Parts of it have been deliberately left longer to help understand what's happening at each stage of this

```
// Find query params here
// https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_comment_query/__construct/
$args = array(
    'type'   => 'comment',
    'status' => 'approve',
);
// Get all approved comments
$comment_arr = get_comments( $args );

// Change array of comments into array of User IDs
// https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pluck/
$list_users = wp_list_pluck( $comment_arr, 'user_id' );

// This will change the array of User IDs into another array this time containing the number of times a value appears
// https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php
$totals = array_count_values( $list_users );

// Option one - loop through the totals array to get the user data from each user ID returned in the key
foreach ( $totals as $user => $n_of_comments ) {
    // https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_userdata/
    $user_obj = get_userdata( $user );
}

// Option two
// - Flips the keys and values round ( https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php ) then
// Implode array to get a list of User IDs to pass to a single query ( https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php )
$list_in_order = implode( ',', array_flip( $totals ) );

$args  = array(
    'include' => $list_in_order,
    'orderby' => 'include',
);
$users = get_users( $args );
    foreach ( $users as $user ) {
    // code
}
```

Comment: thanks mate. option 2 works fine but the only problem is that the code shows all user in front . i put 'number' in option 2 array , it works but the user is not in the right order (user with the most comment). in Codex , i fount order by 'comment_count' but It does not work in either of array

Comment: As mentioned - this code is written by eye - I don't have an easy means to test it. None of my sites allow comments so don't have any comment data to hand either. Having re-read the code I have updated the line with list pluck to use `user_id` which sounds more likely. You should try using some de-bugging along the code - things like [`print_r()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) or [`var_dump()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) will generally show you if you're getting back what you're expecting!

Comment: Still not working. But thank you anyway